# Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException doing config.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof (IUserService)) as IUserService

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I need to get a registered instance of type IUserService in my authentication handler.

```
// Register services

// Build the container.
 var containr = builder.Build();
 var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
 configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

When I run now this line of code:

```
var userService = configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof (IUserService)) as IUserService;
```

I get this exception:

```
   An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code

    Additional information: No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.
```

I do NOT want to create the userservice manually because then I have to resolve also manually the depending classes...

How do I get a certain service when I am not inside a request? Dependency.Resolver is unknown/can not be resolved to use that somehow.

**UPDATE**

I changed my service registration now to:

```
  builder.RegisterType<UserService>()
                   .As<IUserService>()
                   .WithParameter(namedParameter)
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

instead of InstancePerRequestApi()

and resolve the user service like that:

```
var resolver = (AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver)config.DependencyResolver;

            var bla = resolver.GetRootLifetimeScope();
            IUserService userService = bla.Resolve<IUserService>(); // Woot!
```

That works, but what about my former  InstancePerApiRequest ? I would like to keep it too!

**UPDATE**

```
public static void Register(HttpSelfHostConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            var resolver = (AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver)config.DependencyResolver;

            var scope = resolver.GetRootLifetimeScope();
            var userService = scope.Resolve<IUserService>();
            scope.Dispose();

            var authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler(userService);
            var tokenHandler = new TokenHandler();

            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new HttpsHandler());
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AllowCommonVerbsHandler());
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(authenticationHandler);
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(tokenHandler);

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Authentication",
                routeTemplate: "api/users/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "users", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                constraints: null,
                handler: authenticationHandler // Put this handler later on the DefaultApi
            );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "TokenApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
               constraints: null,
               handler: tokenHandler
               );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Start" }
                );

            var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(jsonFormatter));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your authentication handler is a DelegatingHandler. If this is the case, you can access the lifetime scope for the current request using the following code:

```
var scope = request.GetDependencyScope();
var requestScope = scope.GetRequestLifetimeScope();
```

In the code above `request` is the `HttpRequestMessage` instance pass to the `SendAsync` method of the `DelegatingHandler`.

You will not be able to have the constructor dependency in this case. Inside the `SendAsync` method use the code I provided above to resolve the `IUserService` instance when you need to use it.

To create a test for your handler you will need to mock the Web API dependency scope.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// Configure container for test.
var container = builder.Build();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver.ApiRequestTag);
var scope = new AutofacWebApiDependencyScope(lifetimeScope);
request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.DependencyScope, scope);
```

See the `HttpMessageInvoker` for how to unit test a `DelegatingHandler`.

http://nerditorium.danielauger.com/blog/2013/02/05/unit-testing-a-webapi-delegatinghandler-with-a-dependencyscope-via-an-httpmessageinvoker/

Comment: Hello Alex, I am not inside a delegate handler. I am inside the static routes.Register method where I create an authenticationhandler which needs the IUserService in the constructor. See my update.

Comment: Ok now its crashing for everry solution: 1) I have registered the IUserService as InstancePerApiRequest then its crashing in the WebApiRoutesConfig with these lines: var scope = resolver.GetRootLifetimeScope();
            var userService = scope.Resolve<IUserService>(); OR 2) I have registered the IUserService as InstancePerLifetimeScope then its crashing in the integration test when the controller is about to be created: "Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed."

Comment: I have updated my answer to note that constructor injection is not possible in this scenario. This is a limitation imposed by Web API itself.

Comment: I have refactored my business logic and it seems now I do not need the userService instance in the webApiConfig file :-)

Comment: Just in case someone runs into the same issue... these namespace need to be included: using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.WebApi;

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have forgotten to add readonly while creating an object of class while using `IRepository` or you may have forgotten the access modifier before declaring constructor. Hope this might help you.